# GPU doing what it wants

Tags: windows-10, gpu, gaming, nvidia-geforce, directx

I play most of the time Fortnite, have a **Nvidia GeForce MX130** GPU built into a **Asus Vivobook S** notebook and sometimes I get **60 stable FPS** with render distance and all other settings (excluding shadows) set on **epic**, but sometimes, with all settings on low (because when it lags a lot I turn down the video settings) it goes around **20 unstable (from like 5 to 30) FPS**, but on the **Xbox Game Bar** I notice that the GPU is running only around 60/70%. Then, after hours of playing it does more FPSs, but not too many.

Any fix to this?

P.S. Other programs open in the background do not count, I tried to leave them open (Spotify, Chrome, Whatsapp, FL Studio, Discord) then close them and didn't change anything, even though opening them while the game is already open it results in an infinite lag.

Comment: At least one of those applications you listed (Chrome) support hardware acceleration which would take your limited GPU resources towards the browser instead of the game (even if Chrome is minimized).  However, you have not actually provided enough information, to explain your performance problems.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: I think you might be interested in having some more [specs](https://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-MX130-GPU-Benchmarks-and-Specs.258054.0.html) about your graphics card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to close Adobe and Autodesk programs running indesirably in background, they made the CPU work too much and slowed a lot the PC.